# Is there a formal name for functions, whose return type is the type of their argument?

Tags: types, language-agnostic

I am looking for a name to describe unary functions with the same return type as their argument. E.g.

```
int addOne(int arg) { return arg + 1; }
```

but not the following function

```
double divideBy2(int arg) { return ((double)arg) / 2.0; }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When looking for names of functions in Computer Science related to Math, it is often helpful to think in terms of Math. So in Math your question would be

> Need the type of function that has the same [domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_a_function) and [codomain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codomain).

That would be an [Endomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endomorphism)

From Wikipedia

> In mathematics, an endomorphism is a [morphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphism) from a [mathematical object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_object) to itself.

Comment: Why do people like this answer? I am amazed that it currently has 41 views and 4 upvotes. To me this is a common sense answer but apparently it would seem that it is not.